# Exception occurred during event dispatching: java.lang.NullPointerException: Colors cannot be null

Tags: swing, nullpointerexception

I Launch a GUI application, the exception below appears many times(around 8)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Colors cannot be null
at java.awt.GradientPaint.<init>(GradientPaint.java:71)
at it.soltec.ibox.client.components.IBFrameTitlePane.paintTitleBackground(IBFrameTitlePane.java:1065)
at it.soltec.ibox.client.components.IBFrameTitlePane.paintComponent(IBFrameTitlePane.java:1008)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:747)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at it.soltec.ibox.client.IBoxMainFrame$MyPanel.paint(IBoxMainFrame.java:6595)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5131)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:21)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1780)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3375)
at it.soltec.ibox.client.IBoxMainFrame.paint(IBoxMainFrame.java:6014)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

here is the code the exception is refering to

```
    protected void paintTitleBackground(Graphics g) {
    if ( g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Paint savePaint = g2.getPaint();
        boolean isSelected = frame.isSelected();
        int w = getWidth();

       // selectedTitleColor =  Color.WHITE;
       // selectedTitleGradientColor = Color.ORANGE;
        if (isSelected) {
            GradientPaint titleGradient =
                    new GradientPaint(0, 0, selectedTitleColor,
                                              (int) (w * .75), 0, selectedTitleGradientColor);
```

The exact line that causes the exception is this :
    GradientPaint titleGradient = GradientPaint(0, 0, selectedTitleColor,

notice that the variable  selectedTitleColor is already had been set a a value somewhere else in the class ::
      public void installDefaults() {
        selectedTitleColor = UIManager.getColor("InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground");

Answer (score 1):

Compilers do not lie. Try running your code in debug mode and set a break point such that you can view the value of `selectedTitleColor` and `selectedTitleGradientColor`. I guarantee that at least one of those will be `null`.

Comment: I agree with you, compilers do not lie. The problem occurs due to an early use of  `selectedTitleColor`, early means before assigning it a values in the other method 
`selectedTitleColor = UIManager.getColor("InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground");`